# How to detect "viewcontroller" file that contains target action, corresponding to a button click?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

In an ios project, there are numerous viewcontroller files, developed my many people, over a period of time. I launched simulator, and navigated to various screens. In middle of navigation, I want to find which action method will be called when a button is pressed in a screen. How to find it easily without much analyzing the project and without using breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create UIButton category and make sure it is included at your target:

**UIButton+actionsFinder.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (actionsFinder)

@end
```

**UIButton+actionsFinder.m**

```
#import "UIButton+actionsFinder.h"

@implementation UIButton (actionsFinder)


-(void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%s %d %s %@ %@\n %@\n %@", __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, @"Button clicked!\n", NSStringFromSelector(action), [target description], [event description]);
    [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event];
}

@end
```

When any button sends any action you'll see something like this at console:

```
/Users/username/appname/targetname/UIButton+actionsFinder.m 15 -[UIButton(actionsFinder) sendAction:to:forEvent:] Button clicked!

onButton:

<MCViewController: 0x715e280>

<UITouchesEvent: 0x7639f40> timestamp: 23516.9 touches: {( <UITouch: 0x7169240> phase: Ended tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x754e6d0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x754e7d0>> view: <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x7161290; frame = (123.5 38; 73 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71613b0>> location in window: {149, 81.5} previous location in window: {149, 81.5} location in view: {25.5, 23.5} previous location in view: {25.5, 23.5}
```

Note that you'll get the following information:

- selector name at destination class **onButton:** which I had declared
  and linked to buttons onTouchUpInside event action, actual method
  signature looks like

  `-(IBAction)onButton:(id)button;`
- the target description showing the destination class:
  **MCViewController**
- description of the event which fired the action

I was using `__FILE_`_, `__LINE__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macros' to see where NSLog message is coming from.

Comment: Precisely what I needed. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on your button to See:
[image]

Which selector is added to particular touch event.

Or Print `NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);` On each function, so this log will print function name whenever that function will get called.

Comment: respondsToSelector is used to find whether a button responds to an action or not(during run time)? However my question is something very very different.

Comment: When i know the viewcontroller of the file, then i can go and check touchupinside. I want to know how to find that viewcontroller in a big project, without much analysis

Comment: Yes, NSLog(__Pretty_Function__); is a good idea, but not everyone would have added such log in their action methods all the time, in an existing project, when many number of people work on same project on different screens